# Ordering a string with 'leading zeros' in Elastic

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

Is there a way to order following items based on their text and numeric value instead of only string based?

- ABC0001
- BCA0001
- ABC0003
- ABC00002

Currently I get this order

- ABC00002
- ABC0001
- ABC0003
- BCA0001

But I want it like this:

- ABC0001
- ABC00002
- ABC0003
- BCA0001

The config of the field is this:

```
'type'       => 'keyword',
'normalizer' => 'lowercase_normalizer',
```

I didn't see anything in the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sort-search-results.html) about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your strings always have three letters concatenated with a zero-padded number, you can resort to [script-based sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sort-search-results.html#_script_based_sorting). The following script would sort the way you like:

```
POST test/_search
{
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "type": "string",
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": """
          def letters = doc['field'].value.substring(0, 3);
          def numbers = Integer.parseInt(doc['field'].value.substring(3));
          return letters + numbers;
        """
      },
      "order": "asc"
    }
  }
}
```

However, since scripts can kill the performance of your queries depending on your volume of data, a better way would be to create a sub-field with the appropriate analyzer that could do this analysis at indexing time instead of search time. It would be pretty easy to do.

Comment: It's not always 3 characters, but splitting it up in a subfield would be a good idea! I'll mark it as an accepted answer, thanks.